# Event is sometimes triggered more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use the jQuery ajax function to send data to 2 php scripts. The first script inserts the received data into a MySQL db, the second sends emails. The ajax functions are attached to a click event. For some unknown reason sometimes there are 2 or 3 database entries and sent emails even if I click only once. As you can see the 2nd ajax call is embedded into the first one. I tried to use them in parallel. Tried without 'set timeout'-s. I also use here the simplemodal plugin. When the first modal closes, the second opens.

Is there a way to make sure that the click event is triggered only once or to block the ajax requests after 1 successfull call?

Here is a part of the code:

```
$('#confirm').click(function () {

    $('#loading').html("<img style = 'display:inline-block;' src = 'img/loading.gif' />");
    var servtype = $('select option:selected').text();

    $('#type').text(servtype);
    $('#staff_name').text(staff_name);
    $('#day_time').text(a);
    $('#day_date').text(nap + ', ' + dateText);
    $('#type1').text(servtype);
    $('#staff_name1').text(staff_name);
    $('#day_time1').text(a);
    $('#day_date1').text(nap + ', ' + dateText);
    var message = $('#message').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        url: 'add_booking.php',
        data: 'message=' + message + '&date=' + dateText + '&start_end=' + a + '&personid=' + personid + '&servid=' + servid,
        success: function (msg) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
            alert('' + obj.answer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    url: 'send_email.php',
                    data: 'email=zolkazlk@gmail.com&type=' + servtype + '&person=' + staff_name + '&time=' + a + '&date=' + nap + ', ' + dateText,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                        alert('' + obj.answer);
                        $.modal.close();
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            jQuery('#receipt').modal()
                        }, 50);
                    }
                });
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does `$('#confirm').click(function() {})` get initialized more that once? Do you have an online example we can see?

Comment: Try adding an `alert('hi')` just after `$('#confirm').click(function () {` to see if the click is fired several times.

Comment: Zolka, if you want a proper solution to your problem, post your full javascript code somewhere (preferably a working online version) so it can be properly analyzed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$('#confirm').die('click').live('click', function(){....})
```

Finally, in your success call back you can `$('#confirm').die('click')` it again.

This solution makes you sure that there's no any other unwanted event raising. I'm using this solution, because high safety. No doubt that it's better to fix the problem instead of such hacks, but sometimes it's very time consuming and you don't like to trace your team member codes.

Comment: You can also refactor the anonymous function and have a named one like onClick. Then use .unbind(onClick).bind(onClick).

Comment: Reza, you should really get some more experience before you post such solutions. This is the second time today you posted a `.unbind(onClick).bind(onClick)` which is completely redundant and bad practice (unless it is really necessary, which it is not here)

Comment: I changed the code to $('#confirm').die('click').live('click', function(){....}), run 10-15 tests and there was only 1 entry per click. Looks like it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Richard, I don't remember my first time. As I said, it's the most safe practice. I'm professional in UI engineering since 2008, manage lots of enterprise applications. I've experience of debugging and maintenance cost, which is not really heavy for small apps. The performance cost is also not remarkable in small application.

Comment: It's not about performance cost, but writing good code and teaching good practice. The fact that his click is initiated multiple times suggest that his code has a flaw. This is just a workaround to 'ignore' the initial error, instead of fixing the code. Sure it'll work, but next time the same mistake will be made due to misunderstanding of the logic.

Comment: it is not the correct one. Your answer has been accepted by someone who doesn't know what he's doing himself. Let's end this conversation :-)

Comment: @Richard: And I advise you to read what I wrote, more carefully.

Comment: The original issue here is a fundamental lack of understanding of the framework.. You cannot patch that with a hotfix like this one. Your preaching the wrong message..

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery function that can queue ajax calls and I'm sure you can use it.

Here is the code:

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});
var currAjaxCalls = [];
var count = 0;
$.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {
    count++
    if(ajaxOpts.dequeue == true && count > 0) {

        for(var i=0; i<currAjaxCalls.length; i++) {
            currAjaxCalls[i].abort();
        }
        ajaxQueue.dequeue();
    }
        // hold the original complete function
        var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;
        var oldBeforeSend = ajaxOpts.beforeSend;
        count++;
        // queue our ajax request
        ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {
            // create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue
            ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
                // fire the original complete if it was there
                /*if (oldComplete) {
                    currAjaxCalls.slice(1);
                    oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);
                }*/
                $('.cloader').hide();
                next(); // run the next query in the queue
            };
            ajaxOpts.beforeSend = function() {
                if (oldBeforeSend) {
                    currAjaxCalls.slice(1);
                    oldBeforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            };

            // run the query
            currAjaxCalls[currAjaxCalls.length] = $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
        });
};
$.clearAjaxQueue = function() {
    $.ajaxQueue("dequeue");
};
```

Comment: This is probably not the issue though. According to the Topic Starter, one click results in multiple entries.

Comment: It's true, but that one click seems to trigger multiple ajax calls. Using $.ajaxQueue, you can control them, and you can also debug your calls more easily.